# VB.NET Linq To Objects Intersect Returning Objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

How do you get a collection of objects from an intersection of an object array and a string array?

For example, I have a collection of objects (class Person), and a string array of names:

```
Public Class Person
    Public lastName As String
    Public firstName As String
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim personArray As List(Of Person)
        Dim p1 As Person = New Person("Bill", "Fitch") : personArray.Add(p1)
        Dim p2 As Person = New Person("Randy", "Roberts") : personArray.Add(p2)
        Dim p3 As Person = New Person("Miles", "Johnson") : personArray.Add(p3)
        Dim p4 As Person = New Person("Sandy", "Smith") : personArray.Add(p4)

        Dim arrayNames() As String = {"Jones", "Roberts", "Smith", "Teague"}

        'The Linq code
        Dim query = From myPerson In personArray
                    Where myPerson.lastName = arrayNames
                    Select myPerson
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course the Linq code does not work but what Linq does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Contains:

```
    Dim query = From myPerson In personArray
                Where arrayNames.Contains(myPerson.lastName)
                Select myPerson
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes it just takes a nudge!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join:

```
Dim query = From p As Person In personArray
            Join lastName As String In arrayNames On p.lastName Equals lastName
            Select p
```

And here is the full code, if you want to test it (I changed your code slightly, to make sure it compiles).

```
Public Class Form1
  Public Class Person
    Public lastName As String
    Public firstName As String
    Sub New(firstName As String, lastName As String)
      Me.lastName = lastName
      Me.firstName = firstName
    End Sub
  End Class

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim personArray As New List(Of Person)({
      New Person("Bill", "Fitch"),
      New Person("Randy", "Roberts"),
      New Person("Miles", "Johnson"),
      New Person("Sandy", "Smith")
    })

    Dim arrayNames() As String = {"Jones", "Roberts", "Smith", "Teague"}

    Dim query = From p As Person In personArray
                Join lastName As String In arrayNames On p.lastName Equals lastName
                Select p
  End Sub
End Class
```